# PHP HttpInvalidParamException HttpRequestException couldn't resolve host name; name lookup timed out

Tags: php

I am getting the below exception when using PHP (5.3.22) HttpRequest

```
exception 'HttpInvalidParamException' with message 'Empty or too short HTTP message: ''' in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/myapp/info.php:0
 inner exception 'HttpRequestException' with message 'couldn't resolve host name; name lookup timed out (http://somesite.com)'
```

This has been **working well until today**. No errors in apache logs. From the server I am able to ping the target site and also nslookup is returning the ip for that site.

I restarted apache as well as the server but the problem persists. HttpRequest is throwing exception (on send()) for all the urls other than the host site (localhost).

Is there any place/logs to check where I can track this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wonder what is the problem but after a day it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the resolver IP using by your command line ping and nslookup may be different than the one chosen by Apache / PHP. Can you verify that all your resolvers are up and answering DNS queries?

Comment: sometimes after I do a nslookup it works and after some time again the problem. still working on it.

Comment: So your resolvers stop responding? This could be a routing problem to your resolvers or the resolvers themselves having issues. Are you able to use other resolvers?

Comment: After a day it started to work again :).

Comment: If you are no longer looking for an answer you should close this question or add the solution yourself and mark it as answered.

Comment: I can't close the question as I don't have enough reputation.